# Corporate / facility policies

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document-set

In our company, Corporate issues directives which are then implemented by the Facilities as their specific policies. Each facility has their own complete set of policy documents. I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement document library(s) for this. There's a Corporate subsite which has pages in it, one per facility.

My challenge is if I put all the documents into one document library, I need to ensure that each facility can only see and modify their own documents, not those of others. There are also sub-roles within each facility which will need different permissions.

I was thinking of having one Document Set per facility. The View of the Document Library that they would see on their facility specific page would display only their documents. To do this I would need to enforce that a facility-specific property would be set on each and every document that was dragged into the Document Library from their page, perhaps with Document Sets like this:
https://sharepointmaven.com/document-sets-hidden-gem-sharepoint/

This would then allow those in the Corporate role to see all the documents rolled-up nicely into a Document Library view using "group by" to aggregate each facility's documents.

Should this plan work or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

This could work.  You could also use a strategy using Permissions Groups (creating one for Corporate/Leadership, and creating one for each area, with appropriate levels therein).

Comment: thanks for your reply. It looks like as you replied, I also changed the link in my post. Still sounds ok?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

An alternativ solution could be to have a library per facility and manage the permissions either by AD sec group or SPgroup. The end users will only see their library and you could enhance the solution by using a search web part on any overview pages. The search resultat is automaticly security trimmed.